# Is there an age limit on wire in NEC?

Tags: electrical, wire

I have unused 12-3 wire dated 1992.  It seems fine.  Is there a code limitation that says it can’t be used?  I couldn’t find one.

Comment: Not a duplicate this is wire not in use, as long as the outer covering is good it will be fine there is no limit on the age of the wire but it needs to be serviceable (good condition).

Answer (score 2):

There is no limit to the age of the wire, even old knob & tube can be used to maintain historical accuracy. The one place I would modify this statement is on aluminum wire but code allows repair with the same type of device or material without upgrading. 
As far as your 12-3 if it has not been in the sun so the outer thermoplastic covering is good it can be used the same as a brand new roll of 12/3. Since you can read the listing information it is fine.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the conditions in which it was stored corrosion can actually migrate under the insulation. This is much more of a consideration for smaller gauges used in electronics. For house wiring it's probably negligible.

That being said, I would imagine the insulation and the jacket on 27 year old cable may be dried out and brittle. If it were me, I would get new cable.